# Too many input arguments error

Tags: matlab

I am trying to run my function. it shows

> ```
> [root, ni]=value1(xu,xl,acceptable)
> Error using value1
> Too many input arguments.
> ```

```
function[root, ni]=value1(xu,xl,acceptable)
    fu=HW10B(xu);
    fl=HW10B(xl);
    Err=1;
    N=0;
    if fu*fl>=0
    end
    while Err>=acceptable;
        m=(xu+xl)/2;
        fm=HW10B(m)
        if fm*fu<0;
            fl=m;
        else fu=m;
            Err=abs(xu-xl)/xu*100;
        end
        N=N+1;
    end

function [ y] = HW10B( x)
%equation of x
y=3*x^3-8*x^2-4*x+9;
end

root=m;
ni=N;
end
```

Comment: I saved 2 m flie: HW10B.m and value1.m

Comment: How are you calling `value1`? Do you have a variable in your workspace called `value1`?

Comment: `xu` and `xl` should both be scalars, as should `acceptable`. What are you trying to feed your function?

Comment: How do you call the function?

Answer (score 1):

```
function[m, N]=value1(xu,xl,acceptable)
y=@(x)3*x.^3-8.*x.^2-4.*x+9;%//Used anonymous function instead of private
fu=y(xu);%//Used above definition
fl=y(xl);
Err=1;%//Initialise error
N=0;%//Initialise counter
while Err>=acceptable && N<1e4;%//check for convergence
    m=(fu+fl)/2;%//Get new midpoint
    fm=y(m);%//Get value at midpoint
    if fm*fu<0;%//Get left or right value to move
        fl=m;
    else
        fu=m;
        Err=abs(fu-fl)/fu*100;%//Calculate the error
    end
    N=N+1;%//Update iteration counter
end
end
```

Call it from the command line:

```
xu=15;xl=2;acceptable=1e-3;
[root, ni]=value1(xu,xl,acceptable)
root =
    2.7554
ni =
    29
```

As you can see I cleaned up your code quite a bit. Using the two separate storage variables at the end of the code was just taking up more space than necessary. The `if` statement `fu*fl>0` did not do anything, thus I chucked it out. Finally, you needed to update your values in your functions, thus using the `fl`, `fx` and `fm`, not the `xu` and `xl`.

If you call the function *exactly* as I showed you from the command line (with your own values of course), it should not throw any errors.

What happens in your original code is that you calculate everything once for the input variables, get an error which is larger than `acceptable` and therefore executes again, taking the same input arguments, returning the same error as before, which is still larger than `acceptable`. This is what we call an infinite loop. I suggest you check for it using a maximum number of iterations, i.e.

```
while Err>=acceptable && N<1e4
```

and change the `1e4` to whatever maximum number of iterations you want to have. If you accidentally end up going infinite, this counter will kill it without having to resort to <kbd>crtl</kbd>-<kbd>c</kbd> or equivalents.